# Hashmap of ostringstream?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to have a map or an unordered_map of ostringstream? How efficient it is? I want to populate streams by "id":

```
my_logs["info"] << "stuff"
my_logs["info"] << "stuff"
my_logs["debug"] << "stuff"
```

Comment: Yes.   But  using my_logs(foo) is more flexible (since it allows you to change the type of my_logs without changing other code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The only requirement that either `std::map` nor `std::unordered_map` place on `operator[]` for the `mapped_type` is that it be DefaultConstructible. Since `std::ostringstream` is DefaultConstructible - this is perfectly valid code.

It's as efficient as map lookup - whether that's efficient enough depends on the rest of your program. If you're logging stuff through `ostringstream`, I doubt the additional map lookup will be significant to the rest of the logging. But, if it's a concern, you can simply keep references instead:

```
auto&& log_info = my_logs["info"];
// ...

log_info << blah;
```

and use the references. References aren't invalidated by either map (unless you erase the subsequent logs).

Comment: Quick question: how can i detect remains on my buffer?